# slurm: Fatal Error: No front end nodes defined

Tags: ubuntu, slurm

I was installing SLURM to set up a small cluster at home for Molecular Dynamics Simulations on Ubuntu Server.

I have installed it according to the instructions listed here:
http://54.194.218.233/philipwfowler/2016/04/28/setting-up-a-gromacs-cluster/5/

My configuration file looks like this:

http://txt.do/dppin

When starting slurmctld I get this error message:

http://txt.do/dppib

Has anyone ever experienced this error, I'm kind of helpless as there is not information on the web.

Best regards,

TheCShaprFreak

Answer (score 0):

Change the #ComputeNodes section in your config according to [0]:

- HPCompaq is your Head Node (ensure slurmctld is running)
- optiplex790 is your Compute Node (ensure slurmd is running)

> Nodename=optiplex790 NodeAddr=x.x.x.x RealMemory=XY Sockets=XY
>   CoresPerSocket=XY State=UNKNOWN
>
> PartitionName=debug Nodes=optiplex790 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE
>   State=UP

[0] https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Hpc-cluster-basic.png/317px-Hpc-cluster-basic.png

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the `slurmctld-wlm-emulator` package. Your `slurmctld` is pointing to the `emulator` instead of the `real package`.